# Accessing returned object in Loop

Tags: java, object, return

I had a quick question, Right now I have a method that returns a populated DTO object, in another class I am calling that method, and then trying to get access to some of the values that are on the returned Object. I am having trouble figuring out what the syntax should be to accomplish this. It is returning "result". I am currently getting an error:

"Null pointer access: The variable result can only be null at this location"

The DTO that I am returning contains a List and I want to get access to one of the values on that list. Below is my code snippet. Thank you for your help!

---

```
for (Integer i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
        //  System.out.println(array.get(i));

            GetAccountRewardSummaryRequest request = new GetAccountRewardSummaryRequest();
            AccountRewardSummaryDTO result = null;

            request.accountKey =  new AccountIdDTO(array.get(i)); 

            RewardServicesImpl rewardServicesImpl = new RewardServicesImpl();

            rewardServicesImpl.getAccountRewardSummary(request);

            // This will return an AccountRewardSummaryDTO, print out and see if it is returning properly

            System.out.println(result.rewards.get(6));

        //  System.out.println(request.accountKey);

        }
```

Comment: `result` is null. You set it to null. It can only be null unless you set it to something else. Without any context it's unclear what else you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear from your question, but I *suspect* that this:

```
rewardServicesImpl.getAccountRewardSummary(request);
```

should be:

```
result = rewardServicesImpl.getAccountRewardSummary(request);
```

If you want to use the value returned from a method, you need to *do* something with it.

Your code would be clearer if you didn't declare the `result` variable until you needed it though - and there's no point in using `Integer` here instead of `int`. Additionally, unless you really can't reuse the service, you might as well create that *once*:

```
RewardServices service = new RewardServicesImpl();
for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
    GetAccountRewardSummaryRequest request = new GetAccountRewardSummaryRequest();
    request.accountKey =  new AccountIdDTO(array.get(i)); 
    AccountRewardSummaryDTO result = service.getAccountRewardSummary(request);
    System.out.println(result.rewards.get(6));
}
```

Also, as noted, the fact that your variable called `array` clearly isn't an array variable is confusing.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, looking at it now it was unclear, but your explanation was perfect.